# Matching and Generating new IDs rows in R

Tags: r, dataset

I'm matching a set of data on an `ID_match` variable and then I am trying create a new ID variable expading each row belonging to the same `ID_match` and assigning a dummy variable `reference`. For small samples, the code below works fine:

```
df=data.frame(ID_match=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,4)), ID_row=1:9)

df$reference = 0
df$new_id = 0

for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {

  print(i)
  df_s = df[i,]
  df_s$reference[1]=1
  df_match=df[df$ID_match==df_s$ID_match[1] & df$ID_row!=df_s$ID_row[1],]
  df_s = rbind(df_s,df_match)
  df_s$new_id=i

  if(i==1){

    df_s1=df_s
    next
  }

  df_s1 = rbind(df_s, df_s1)  

}

rownames(df_s1) = 1:dim(df_s1)[1]

df_s1 = dplyr::select(df_s1,-ID_row)
```

Where `df` is transformed from the following structure:

```
  ID_match ID_row reference new_id
1        1      1         0      0
2        1      2         0      0
3        1      3         0      0
4        2      4         0      0
5        2      5         0      0
6        3      6         0      0
7        3      7         0      0
8        3      8         0      0
9        3      9         0      0
```

To `df_s1`'s new one:

```
   ID_match reference new_id
1         3         1      9
2         3         0      9
3         3         0      9
4         3         0      9
5         3         1      8
6         3         0      8
7         3         0      8
8         3         0      8
9         3         1      7
10        3         0      7
11        3         0      7
12        3         0      7
13        3         1      6
14        3         0      6
15        3         0      6
16        3         0      6
17        2         1      5
18        2         0      5
19        2         1      4
20        2         0      4
21        1         1      3
22        1         0      3
23        1         0      3
24        1         1      2
25        1         0      2
26        1         0      2
27        1         1      1
28        1         0      1
29        1         0      1
```

However the code is considerably slower for samples of a higher sizer. Do you guys know any options of how to make this faster?

**EDIT:** @machine's answer was probably correct, considering the previous version of the question. But I had to edit it a bit to consider an uneven number of IDs.

Comment: may i ask how big is your actual `df`? because you are duplicating the number of rows n^2 times for each id. you might face out of memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual dataset is large, you will face out of memory issues very quickly because you are duplicating the number of rows n^2 times for each id.

If you have not hit the limit, here is an option using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
df=data.frame(ID_match=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,4)), ID_row=1:9)
setDT(df)[, .(reference=rep(replace(rep(0L, .N), 1L, 1L), .N), 
    new_id=rep(.I, each=.N)), ID_match][
        .N:1L]
```

Comment: If I needed to add more variables, without changing their properties, how would that work on `data.table`? Say, I had addtional variables A, B, C... Variables which I would like to preserve their relationship between matched observations.

Comment: You mean more columns? Yeah you can add them inside the .()